# conda install matplotlib results in huge list on incompatibilities

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

I have a conda env that I build from a requirements.yml file that I obtained from a classmate so we could work on a project together. I tried installing matplotlib and it resulted in a gigantic list of incompatibilities that I don't think I could even start tackling manually.

Here are the most important packages I'm using (the ones that have come up in a few other posts I've looked at and what the error looks like):

- python 3.9.7
- tensorflow 2.6.0
- anaconda 4.11
- numpy 1.21.2
- tornado 6.1

Is there a way of adressing this without going into every line of the error?:

The part of the error containing matplotlib incompatibilities specifically:

```
- matplotlib -> cycler[version='>=0.10'] -> six[version='>=1.5']
  - matplotlib -> libpng[version='>=1.6.32,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.35,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.36,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']
  - matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.0,<3.5.1.0a0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.15.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0']
  - matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.0,<3.5.1.0a0'] -> packaging[version='>=20.0']
  - matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.0,<3.5.1.0a0'] -> pyparsing[version='>=2.0.3,!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6|>=2.2.1']
  - matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.0,<3.5.1.0a0'] -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.1|>=2.7']
  - matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> blas[version='*|1.0',build=mkl]
  - matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> icc_rt[version='>=13.1.6|>=2019.0.0|>=16.0.4']
  - matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl-service[version='>=2,<3.0a0|>=2.3.0,<3.0a0']
  - matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.0,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.1,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0|>=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0|>=2019.1,<2021.0a0|>=2019.3,<2021.0a0|>=2019.4,<2021.0a0|>=2021.2.0,<2022.0a0|>=2021.3.0,<2022.0a0|>=2019.4,<2020.0a0']
  - matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> mkl_random[version='>=1.0.2,<2.0a0|>=1.2.1,<2.0a0|>=1.0.4,<2.0a0']
  - matplotlib -> numpy[version='>=1.14.6,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.11.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.3|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.4|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.5|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.14.6|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.0|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.1|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.2|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.3|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.15.4|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.0|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.1|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.2|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.3|1.16.4|1.16.4|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.5|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.17.2.*|1.17.3.*|1.17.4.*|1.18.1.*|1.18.5.*|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.1|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.17.0|1.17.0|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|1.9.3|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0',build='py27h0bb1d87_7|py35h5c71026_7|py36h5c71026_7|py27h0bb1d87_8|py35h4a99626_9|py27hfef472a_9|py37h8128ebf_9|py36h8128ebf_9|py35h8128ebf_9|py27h2753ae9_9|py27h2753ae9_10|py36h8128ebf_11|py37h2a9b21d_11|py36h2a9b21d_11|py27hb1d0314_11|py37hc3f5095_12|py38hc3f5095_12|py27h917549b_1|py35h5c71026_0|py27h0bb1d87_0|py35h5c71026_0|py27h0bb1d87_0|py27h0bb1d87_1|py36h5c71026_1|py37h5c71026_2|py27h0bb1d87_2|py27h0bb1d87_3|py36h5c71026_3|py27h0bb1d87_4|py37h5c71026_4|py36h5c71026_4|py35h4a99626_4|py37h8128ebf_4|py27h2753ae9_4|py35h8128ebf_4|py38hc3f5095_4|py37hc3f5095_5|py27hb1d0314_5|py36hc3f5095_5|py35h4a99626_0|py37h4a99626_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py35h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py37h8128ebf_0|py36h8128ebf_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_1|py27hb1d0314_1|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_1|py27hb1d0314_1|py27hb1d0314_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36h5bb6eb2_3|py38h5bb6eb2_3|py37hc2deb75_0|py39h0829f74_0|py37h0829f74_0|py38h0829f74_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py37hc2deb75_0|py38hc2deb75_0|py39hc2deb75_0|py38haf7ebc8_0|py39haf7ebc8_0|py37haf7ebc8_0|py39hbd0edd7_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py36ha3acd2a_0|py37ha3acd2a_0|py38ha3acd2a_0|py39h5bb6eb2_3|py37h5bb6eb2_3|py39h2e04a8b_1|py38hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_0|py36hc3f5095_1|py37hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py27hb1d0314_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py27h2753ae9_1|py36h8128ebf_0|py27h2753ae9_0|py27hfef472a_0|py36h4a99626_0|py36h8128ebf_4|py36hc3f5095_0|py37hc3f5095_0|py37h5c71026_3|py36h5c71026_2|py37h5c71026_1|py37h5c71026_0|py36h5c71026_0|py36h5c71026_0|py36h555522e_1|py35h555522e_1|py36hc3f5095_12|py27hb1d0314_12|py37h8128ebf_11|py37h8128ebf_10|py36h8128ebf_10|py35h8128ebf_10|py37h4a99626_9|py36h4a99626_9|py35h4a99626_8|py37h5c71026_8|py36h5c71026_8|py37h5c71026_7|py27h0bb1d87_7|py37h5c71026_7|py36h5c71026_7|py27h0bb1d87_6|py36h5c71026_6|py37h5c71026_6']
  - matplotlib -> pyparsing
  - matplotlib -> python-dateutil
  - matplotlib -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
  - matplotlib -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.0.25123,<15.0a0|>=14.0.25420|>=14.15.26706|>=14.27.29016|>=14.16.27012']
  - matplotlib -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1e,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1f,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a']
  - matplotlib -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> pip
  - matplotlib -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.28.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0|>=3.31.1,<4.0a0|>=3.33.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.4,<4.0a0|>=3.36.0,<4.0a0|>=3.32.3,<4.0a0|>=3.30.0,<4.0a0|>=3.35.1,<4.0a0']
  - matplotlib -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
  - matplotlib -> pytz
  - matplotlib -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
  - matplotlib -> tornado -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26|>=2020.06.20']
  - matplotlib -> vc[version='14.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0|9.*']
  - matplotlib -> vs2015_runtime[version='>=14.16.27012,<15.0a0']
  - matplotlib -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Couldn't install matplotlib 3.5.1 after I installed tensorflow 2.6.0. I could solve it by using using conda-forge (see https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib):

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```